# GetWindowTextA unable to get the text of ComboBox MFC C++

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I'm using `GetWindowTextA` to get the text of ComboBox but it will be an empty string `""` even the `hwnd` is correct.

No problem when using `GetWindowTextA` to get the text from other class, but it won't work for the class `ComboBox`. Is it something related to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windowsx/nf-windowsx-combobox_gettext) that need other function to get text from ComboBox?

Thanks.

---

Editied:

The combobox is from a control in some other app's window

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

        POINT pt;
        Sleep(3000);
        GetCursorPos(&pt);

        HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pt); 

        char class_name[100];
        char title[100];

        GetClassNameA(hWnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
        GetWindowTextA(hWnd,title,sizeof(title));

        cout <<"Window name : "<<title<<endl;
        cout <<"Class name  : "<<class_name<<endl;

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: From the documentation: *However, GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application.* Does this apply to you?

Comment: Nope, the application is the same. In the same dialog, I can get the text of all the objects with the class Static and Button, except ComboBox.

Comment: How are you using it, and are you specifically wanting the "A" version of GetWindowText? Normal usage is to not specify the "A" or "W" and just  `GetWindowText` to a `CString`.

Comment: Also, where are you trying to use it? Don't try use it inside the selection changed handler.

Comment: I don't suppose `GetDlgItemText` using your dialog as the hwnd, and the actual ID as the child id would do what you want?

Comment: @acraig5075 I need the 'A' version because I have 3 arguments. I used it in a CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried `GetDlgItemText` but I'm not sure the `nIDDlgItem` of ComboBox. If it is `IDC_COMBO`, then I still get the empty string.

Comment: Its the ID of your combobox control in your dialog script that built your  resource kit for your application. Its typically defined in a resource.h, and included in both the resource script (.rc file) and any source files that need those ids (like this one).

Comment: @WhozCraig  I see. That means I need to get the `nIDDlgItem` of that ComboBox? I also tried to use my code to get the text of a ComboBox inside Visual Studio but it shows empty too. 

Is it the reason that stated in the `GetWindowText` documentation: _However, GetWindowText cannot retrieve the text of a control in another application._ But, I can get the other text that belongs to class `Static` and `Button`.

Comment: What is the style of your combo box? `CBS_SIMPLE`, `CBS_DROPDOWN`, `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`? Are  you trying to get the text of the edit (static) control or the selected item from the list?

Comment: @VladFeinstein the style is `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST`, I'm trying to get the text of the selected item

Comment: @Joshua_0101 Check the return value of [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) and if it's 0, call [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)

Comment: When I tried to get the text of the ComboBox, the `GetWindowText` return 0 but `GetLastError` also return 0. From the documentation of `GetWindowText`, in **Return value** part, it mentioned that _This function cannot retrieve the text of an edit control in another application._ Is it ComboBox also consider as `Edit` control? As I know `GetWindowText` can't get the text in `Edit` control but I'm not sure ComboBox is included or not.

Comment: Under normal circumstances a drop down list combo maps to a integer index and you then use GetLBText to retrieve the text. Only when the combo is editable does it map to a string.

Comment: @Joshua_0101 The very first comment asked that question and you replied "*nope, the application is the same*". So, which one is it?

Comment: @dxiv Yes, the application that I want to retrieve the text is the same. The application included `Button`, `Static` and `ComboBox`. Based on this statement,  _This function cannot retrieve the text of an edit control in another application_ , if a `ComboBox` is considered as an edit control, means that `GetWindowText` cannot be used to achieve my goal. So, I think now the question will be, is it a `ComboBox` considered as an edit control?  The reply from @Andrew Truckle might answered this.

Comment: @Joshua_0101 "*the application that I want to retrieve the text is the same*" ...the same as *what*? Is this about getting the text from a control created by your own process, or from a control in some other app's window "*similar to Spy++*" as you write elsewhere? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64496633/edit) your question to clarify, and post the actual code that fails. As is now, there is not enough information to even guess what the problem is.

Comment: The question is updated and I think this article might help [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833)

Comment: @Joshua_0101 The page you linked explains both why it doesn't work in that case (as stated in the reference docs), and how to do it instead. I am not sure what exactly the question is now, except maybe you could post a self-answer by essentially copy/pasting from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `TCHAR szBuf[100];` and using `SendMessage` will be done.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

        POINT pt;
        Sleep(3000);
        GetCursorPos(&pt);

        HWND hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pt); 

        char class_name[100];
        char title[100];
        TCHAR szBuf[100];

        GetClassNameA(hWnd,class_name, sizeof(class_name));
        GetWindowTextA(hWnd,title,sizeof(title));
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, 100, (LPARAM)szBuf);

        //cout <<"Window name : "<<title<<endl;
        cout <<"Class name  : "<<class_name<<endl;
        wcout <<"Window name  : "<<szBuf<<endl;

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've added a CComboBox variable to your dialog class, using the "Add Control Variable" wizard, as described here [Add a member variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/adding-a-member-variable-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019), you can readily use the CComboBox methods to retrieve the text of the selected combo item, as illustrated below:

```
void CMFCDlgAppDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CString itemText;
    m_Combo.GetLBText(m_Combo.GetCurSel(), itemText);
    AfxMessageBox(itemText);
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the method used on the application that created by ourselves. I'm trying to achieve something similar to Spy++, get the object's details based on the window handle.

Comment: @Joshua_0101 you should have mentioned this in your question. Please add some more relevant code to the question. But anyway, I'm not even sure you can read the text f a control from another process easily. Google _GetWIndowText other process_ for more information.